# Arduino android e socket

Tags: android, socket, arduino

Como fazer o arduino se comunicar com o android utilizando o protocolo de rede socket, para enviar e receber dados? trafegando informações captadas no arduíno, neste caso de umidade e temperatura.

Comment: Consegui realizar a comunicação entre ambos, sucesso no projeto :)